# How to get the input log message detail when defining watcher?

Tags: elasticsearch-watcher

I am trying to define a watcher in kibana to monitor our logs and send a notification with message detail to our slack channel when an error happens.

Problem is that i can't find a way to get the message detail. I have printed the whole `{{ ctx }}` dict, and found nothing useful there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your query and hit elasticsearch and check the response for the message details. Below example is for multi-bucket aggregation query similarly you can query elasticsearch with you set of query and check the response.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST  http://localhost:9002/filebeat-2019.04.04/_search?pretty=true -d '{"size": 0,"aggs": {"messages": {"filters": {"filters": {"errors": {"match": {"message": "CREDENTIALS"}},"warnings": {"match": {"message": "SUCCESS"}}}}}}}'
```

Response:

```
{
  "took": 9,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": ...,
  "hits": ...,
  "aggregations": {
    "messages": {
      "buckets": {
        "errors": {
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        "warnings": {
          "doc_count": 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the message element from the query and condition used for the watcher.
For example, if your condition was something like this:

```
"condition": {
    "compare": {
      "ctx.payload.hits.total": {
        "gt": 0
      }
    }
  }
```

For this case, the message can be found at this location:

```
ctx.payload.hits.hits.0._source.message
```